# Laravel 5. Merge several Builders to paginate them with "paginate()"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I am trying to merge several builders to paginate search results of them, but this code returning me an error

My SearchController.php

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $string = mb_strtolower($request->input('q'), "UTF-8");
        if ($string != "") {
            // $query = explode(" ", $string);
            $query = $string;
        } else {
            $query = null;
        }

        if ($query != null) {
            $news = $this->searchQuery(new News(), 'title', 'content', $query, false);
            $last = $this->searchQuery(new Last(), 'title', 'description', $query, false);
            $author = $this->searchQuery(new AuthorNews(), 'title', 'description', $query, false);
            $tv = $this->searchQuery(new TvBroadcast(), 'name', 'description', $query, false);
            $program = $this->searchQuery(new TvProgram(), 'name', 'description', $query, false);
            $project = $this->searchQuery(new SpecProject(), 'title', 'description', $query, false);
            $appointments = $this->searchQuery(new Appointment(), 'fio', 'position', $query, false);
            //Новости по авторам
            // $authors = $this->searchAuthor($query);
            // dd($authors);
            // 21520

            $item = $news->merge($last);
            $item = $item->merge($author);
            $item = $item->merge($tv);
            $item = $item->merge($program);
            $item = $item->merge($project);
            $item = $item->merge($appointments);

            $items = $item->paginate(21);

            $items_c = $items->total();
        } else {
            $items = null;
            $items_c = 0;
            $string = null;
        }

        $method = 'index';

        return view('front.search.index', array('items' => $items, 'count' => $items_c, 'q' => $string, 'method' => $method));
    }

    public function searchQuery($model, $attr1, $attr2, $query, $stat, $author = false)
    {
        $items = $model->with('nodes')->whereHas('nodes', function ($q) use ($query, $attr1, $attr2) {
            $q->where('language_id', '=', app()->getLocale())->where(function ($q) use ($query, $attr1, $attr2) {
                $q->where(\DB::raw('lower(' . $attr1 . ')'), 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                    ->orWhere(\DB::raw('lower(' . $attr2 . ')'), 'like', '%' . $query . '%');
            });
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

        if ($stat == true) {
            $items = $items->where('stat', '=', 1);
        }

        if ($author) {
            $items = $items->with(['author', 'author.nodes'])->orWhereHas('author.nodes', function ($q) use ($query) {
                // foreach ($query as $elem) {
                //     $q->where(\DB::raw('lower(title)'), 'like', '%' . $elem . '%');
                // }
                $q->where(\DB::raw('lower(title)'), 'like', '%' . $query . '%');
            });
        }

        return $items;
    }
```

[I have 7 Builders like this and I want to merge them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waTVn.png)

[But when I am running my code I get an error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rv6Y.png)

I also tried union() method and it doesn't work too

Comment: merge only works for the collection, not the Eloquent query builder. you can use [UnionAll()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#unions) to handle this but I am not sure of pagination on it. But to use merge (which is inefficient) you will need to fetch the data and then merge them and do pagination on that collection, which is not a good solution

Comment: I changed merge to unionAll, but it also doesn't work

```
$item = $news->unionAll($last);
$item = $item->unionAll($author);
$item = $item->unionAll($tv);
$item = $item->unionAll($program);
$item = $item->unionAll($project);
$item = $item->unionAll($appointments);
```

Comment: I am sorry you don't need to use `unionALl()` you can use `union()` for this`$query->union($first)->union($second)->get();` But to use union you will need to specify the same number of columns for each table in the union. Have you done that too?